# AWS-CLI acccess to S3 on Linux Machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am wanting to set up a recursive sync from a Linux machine (Fedora) to an AWS S3 bucket.  I am logged into Linux as root and have an AWS Key and Secret associated with a specific AWS user "Lisa".

I have installed aws-cli, s3cmd, and attempted to configure both.  I have verified the aws/configure and aws/credentials files both have a default user and a "Lisa" user with Access Key and Secret pairs.  I receive errors stating that Access is Denied, access key and secret pair not found.  I have researched this on the web and verified that there are no environment variables that could be overriding the configure & credential files.  I have also granted full access permissions to the bucket created through the AWS Console to all logged in users.  I have not rotated the keys, as they were first created a week ago, and I was able to log-in & set-up the AWS console using that same key pair.

What else should I be doing before rotating the keys?

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: Update:  I rotated the AWS keys (Access and Secret) and am still receiving errors.  When I enter 'aws s3 ls', I receive the error **An error occurred (InvalidAccessKeyId) when calling the ListBuckets operation:  The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.**  I get the same error when I use 'aws s3 ls --profile Lisa'.  I verified there are no leading or lagging white spaces in the keys.

Comment: Does the Access Key start with `AKIA`? The Secret Key should be a long jumble of characters.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  The Access Key starts with AKIA and the Secret Key is the jumble.

Comment: I am also not even able to identify what account AWS is trying to use for the access.  I have attempted the command 'aws s3api list-buckets --query Owner.ID' and received the same InvalidAccessKeyId error.  My concern has a couple parts (1) is there an issue being the root user on the computer, and using the Lisa access key / secret, and (2) the bucket was created using AWS console, and has full access granted to all users of the same AWS account, however, I am attempting to access the bucket through AWS-CLI or s3cmd.

Comment: After you "rotated the AWS keys", you would have created a new Access Key and Secret Key. You would then need to provide them to the AWS CLI by using the `aws configure` command. This puts them in the `~/.aws/credentials` file. Did you do all this?

Comment: Yes, I did. I updated the credentials file using the 'aws configure' and 'aws configure --profile = Lisa' command.

Comment: I have also now confirmed that I can connect to AWS S3 using Cloudberry with the same credentials that are not working with the aws-cli

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't configured AWS credentials correctly. Make sure that you have correct access keys in your credentials file. If you don't specify any profiles, awscli uses the default profile.

~/.aws/credentials

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=AKIAIDEFAULTKEY
aws_secret_access_key=Mo9T7WNO….

[Lisa]
aws_access_key_id=AKIAILISASKEY
aws_secret_access_key=H0XevhnC….
```

This command uses the default profile:

> aws s3 ls

This command uses Lisa profile:

> aws s3 ls --profile Lisa

You can set an environment variable to override the default profile.

> export AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE=Lisa

Now this command uses the profile Lisa:

> aws s3 ls

If you don't know which profile is active, you can just invoke the following command:

> aws sts get-caller-identity

Comment: Hi - when I open the ~/.aws/credentials file, I see both the default and Lisa profile, similar to what you have listed above. Then when I try "aws s3 ls", that is when I receive an error saying "An error occurred (InvalidAccessKey) when calling the List Buckets operation:  The AWS access key you provided does not match our records".
I get a similar error when attempting "aws s3 ls --profile Lisa" and then with the "aws sts get-caller-identity" command, I receive a message stating that there is an InvalidClientIDToken.

Comment: It looks like your configuration contains invalid keys. Rotate your credentials in this case (generate a new pair) and make sure that you store the correct values.

Comment: Thank you, vikyol.  Unfortunately, that did not solve the issue.  Any other suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have several terms intermixed, so it's worth knowing the difference:

- **Username and password** is used to login to the web-based management console. They are short, to be human-readable and easy to remember.
- **Access Key** (starting with `AKIA`) and **Secret Key** is used for making API calls. It is also used by the AWS CLI (which makes API calls on your behalf)
- **Key pair** consists of a public and private key, used for authenticating SSH connections. It is a very long block of text.

You mention that an Access Key is not found. This could be because the wrong type of credential is being provided.

Comment: Thank you, John.  Any tips on how to determine what credentials are being provided to AWS?  I am thinking that since I am logged into the machine as root, and the default profile uses the same Access Key and Secret Key as the Lisa profile, there may be a mismatch in what AWS is receiving.  However, when I specify the profile as Lisa for any aws command, I receive the same error as when I do not specify a profile.